# Android KitKat 4.4 Chromium WebView "v8_value_converter_impl.cc" error

Tags: android, webview, chromium

I am building an Android app which contains a couple of webview. The app needs to support KitKat 4.4 at minimum which embeds chromium v30 webview according to [this](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview#webview_faq). I am testing the app on Samsung Galaxy Note 2 running 4.4.2 stock rom, the webview runs very slowly and the logcat is flood with the below error messages:

```
...
03-21 14:11:48.651 29445-29445/com.mylovely.app I/GraphicBuffer: allocate buffer (w:384 h:384 f:1) handle(0x6f64b600) err(0)
03-21 14:11:48.652 29445-29445/com.mylovely.app I/GraphicBuffer: allocate buffer (w:384 h:384 f:1) handle(0x6d715280) err(0)
03-21 14:11:48.652 29445-29445/com.mylovely.app I/GraphicBuffer: allocate buffer (w:128 h:192 f:1) handle(0x6dd99590) err(0)
03-21 14:12:03.996 29445-29884/com.mylovely.app E/chromium: [ERROR:v8_value_converter_impl.cc(405)] Getter for property selectionDirection threw an exception.
03-21 14:12:03.996 29445-29884/com.mylovely.app E/chromium: [ERROR:v8_value_converter_impl.cc(405)] Getter for property selectionEnd threw an exception.
03-21 14:12:03.996 29445-29884/com.mylovely.app E/chromium: [ERROR:v8_value_converter_impl.cc(405)] Getter for property selectionStart threw an exception.
03-21 14:12:04.007 29445-29884/com.mylovely.app E/chromium: [ERROR:v8_value_converter_impl.cc(405)] Getter for property selectionDirection threw an exception.
03-21 14:12:04.007 29445-29884/com.mylovely.app E/chromium: [ERROR:v8_value_converter_impl.cc(405)] Getter for property selectionEnd threw an exception.
03-21 14:12:04.007 29445-29884/com.mylovely.app E/chromium: [ERROR:v8_value_converter_impl.cc(405)] Getter for property selectionStart threw an exception.
... <skipped lots of duplicated error here>

03-21 14:12:05.370 29445-29445/com.mylovely.app I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 41.055MB for 11211498-byte allocation
03-21 14:12:06.285 29445-29445/com.mylovely.app I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 34.448MB for 4285074-byte allocation
03-21 14:12:06.354 29445-29445/com.mylovely.app I/Choreographer: Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-21 14:12:06.356 29445-29445/com.mylovely.app I/GraphicBuffer: allocate buffer (w:384 h:384 f:1) handle(0x637baab0) err(0)
03-21 14:12:06.358 29445-29445/com.mylovely.app I/GraphicBuffer: allocate buffer (w:384 h:384 f:1) handle(0x6e7ee640) err(0)
...
```

I already did some googling and found this seems to be fixed [this chromium ticket](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=259093). But since we cannot update the system webview under 4.4.2 through Google Play. Is there any other way to fix / workaround this issue beside embedding other webview (like [crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/android/embedding_crosswalk.html)) to the app?

Comment: im wondering if there is a way to update the webview's chromium version in kitkat. anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I found out the root cause of the issue. I added some heavy js tasks in the `onProgressChanged` callback, which they would output an null object. This null object could not be serialized and causing the bug in [this chromium ticket](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=259093). As a workaround, I wrapped all the js calls with [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8228281/510577) to slient the output and throttle the js calls in `onProgressChanged` using Guava's `RateLimiter`.